# Get last record in related model

Tags: activerecord, yii2, relationship

I have two models: Person and RentedFilm

Person table fields:

- id
- name

RentedItem fields:

- rid
- film_id
- rent_date

I need to add a new attribute to person model that contains last rent date but I don't know how. Already I have a getRentDates method that hasMany relations in defined inside it.

Would you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare relation like:

```
public function getLastRentItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RentItem::class, ['rid' => 'id'])
        ->orderBy(['rent_date' => SORT_DESC])
        ->limit(1)
        ->one();
}
```

Use it like:

```
$model->lastRentItem ? $model->lastRentItem->rent_date : null;
```

*You have to adjust this code, because i didn't saw yours.